# How to gzip file before sending it to server?

Tags: angular

So when I upload a file, I wish to gzip it before calling rest api and send it to server. There is little documentation online so what is the best way to do it?

I have tried and failed with a couple of npm packages such as pako and gzipy. But when I call gzipy.compress() for example, app wont compile with Can't resolve 'fs'.

Answer (score 0):

You get a "can't resolve FS" because FS stands for fileSystem and will only work on NodeJS, not the browser. The compression would have to be done by JS in the browser. Not entirely sure if JS has access to files at the binary level, but you might have to modify libraries written for node to work on the browser.

You could append the binaries for a bunch of files, and send the concatenated binary to the server, without compression. I suggest you read a little bit more on how compression works, in case what you really want is to send many files with a single call. You might not need the compression part at all.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gzip

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shannon%27s_source_coding_theorem

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huffman_coding

Comment: Well I want to send one file only, not multiple files. So you say I could downsize it without zipping it. It's difficult to understand at this point, it's quite new to me.

Comment: I hate questioning people's questions, but you need to consider the actual savings you get from compression. It really depends on the file. ANyway, some crazy client side tool might do it, so go 4 it!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use jzip-js. Read more here:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/gzip-js

Alternatively this https://stuk.github.io/jszip/ also exists.